# Why didn't Heimdall inform Thor that Odin had gone missing?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

At the start of *Thor: Ragnarok* Surtur says that Odin is not in Asgard. Heimdall could see it because he is all seeing. So why didn't he inform Thor that Odin had gone missing like Thor saw Asgard by Heimdall's vision later on in the movie?

Comment: This is supposition, so I'm not writing this as an answer.  Heimdall might not have known Odin was missing because Loki had taken his place.

Answer (score 7):

#### He was a fugitive

Heimdall isn't around at the beginning of the movie. He's a fugitive of the throne. He can't tell Thor about Odin because he wasn't present.

> **Thor:** Who are you? 
>   **Skurge:** Don't you remember? I'm Skurge. We fought together on Vanaheim. 
>   **Thor:** Right. Where is Heimdall? 
>   **Skurge:** That traitor. No one knows. He's a fugitive of the throne. 
>   **Thor:** Traitor? 
>   **Skurge:** Yeah. You see, Odin charged Heimdall with negligence of duty but he disappeared before the trial. Hard to catch a guy who can see everything in the universe.

#### Thor didn't need him to tell him

In addition to the previous point, regardless of Heimdall's ability to have known that Thor had returned and thus go tell him, Thor did not need Heimdall's help. It takes him all of 2 minutes in the film to realize that Odin is Loki and that the real Odin was missing. It wouldn't have added anything to the film to have him show up and tell Thor.

Comment: Although, being a fugitive, Heimdall still has his abilities and powers and had the ability to talk to Thor (like he did in later parts of Thor:Ragnarok). You saying Heimdall can't tell Thor about Odin just because he wasn't there is like saying He's not all seeing Heimdall. in *Skurge's* words: **Hard to catch a guy who can see everything**,  So your answer **He can't tell Thor about Odin because he wasn't there.** seems hardly the good explanation and aint match with the dialog you put in

Comment: @sanpaco I agree with vishwa. He could have shown thor like he did later on the movie.

Comment: @Vishwa I don't think simply having a super ability is a good argument for why it would have made any logical sense for him to come tell Thor about Odin. He was on the run as a fugitive and Thor ultimately had no trouble figuring out the truth without Heimdall's help. It would not have added anything to the movie and it is perfectly logical for him not to have been around to tell Thor since he was a fugitive.